# Import file into a json key

Tags: python

I want my program to go into a file and take all of the lines and put them into a json key.

The code:

```
def import_proxies():
    global proxies_json
    proxies_json = {'http': {}}
    with open("proxies.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as proxy_file:
        for line in proxy_file:
            val = line.split()
            proxies_json[['http'][val]] = val
            print(proxies_json)


import_proxies()

My erorr: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

What I want it to do is is import the file lines as values in the `http` key (`proxies_json = {'http': {}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proxies_json seems to be a dictionary. So something like this should work

```
def import_proxies():
    global proxies_json
    proxies_json = {'http': {}}
    with open("proxies.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as proxy_file:
        for line in proxy_file:
            val = line.split()
            data = proxies_json.get('http', {})
            for item in val:
                data[item] = item
            proxies_json['http'] = data
    print(proxies_json)
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: this is what my file looks like

```1.20.101.149:44778
1.179.144.180:80
1.179.206.161:59033
1.0.189.15:8080
114.98.24.76:4216``` (with newlines)

Comment: so `val = line.split()` will gives a list like `["1.20.101.149:44778"]`. So how do want your data to be stored, a big list of the all values or key/value pair ? Please provide a format of  how your stored data should look like.

Comment: i want to be stored like so: `{'http': {LINES_OF_FILE}}`

Comment: So there are two ways we can store the data in above mentioned format. one as a string eg : `{ "http" : "big_string_of_all_lines"}` else in list, `{ "http" : ["line1", "line2"]}`. Second one would be better when accessing the data. I don't think it is a good idea to store it as you have mentioned as it requires key/value pair as `{"http" : { "line1" : "line1", "line2" : "line2"}. This will have same data in key as well value, which is not very useful and leads to data duplication.